# Regular Expression, Match Between Single Quotes after Certain String

Tags: regex

I am trying to match string between single quotes directly after another specific string.  I created the following regular expression but it doesn't meet my needs if there is more than one property on a given line.

```
(?<=itemId:)(.*)'(.*)'
```

I am trying to match the string between single quotes after itemId in the following example:

looking to match:**reasonFldSt**

```
{
        itemId: 'reasonFldSt',
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        layout: 'hbox',
        width: 550,
        margin: myMargin,
```

Looking for same string when there is more than one property on a line

Looking to match:**minDebitFld**

```
{ itemId: 'minDebitFld', fieldLabel: 'Min Bal', xtype: 'numberfield' },
```

Edit:
I am using the built in find function in Visual Studio IDE that supports regular expressions to query.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse a javascript object. Why not use built in object notation to retrieve the value?

Comment: javascript do not have **lookbehind** (`(?<=...)`)

Comment: @r3mus The itemId's i'm after are the identifiers in ExtJS for querying components.  They can be nested in different json objects at different levels.  I'm hoping, for instance, to find all itemId's in a specific component so I can avoid looking through the code to find the itemId's when i forget the names. So, that won't work unfort.

Comment: Using RegEx to parse json is simply the wrong way to go about finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: @tenub I respectfully disagree, I am already in the ide coding the controller and am simply looking to find the itemIds to reference in another js file open within the IDE too.  I think this is a quick way to get all matches while I'm still in the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
/itemId:\s?'(.+?)'/g
```

This way you only go for the value of `itemId`. Global-flag is optional, depends whether your input is on one line or on multiple lines.

See the [example@regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zH8qL9).

Since you're using VisualStudios search function you have to omit the delimiters and the flag:

```
itemId:\s?'(.+?)'
```

If you want to exclude the term *itemId* from your search result you can use

```
(?<=itemId:\s?)'.+?'
```

This way VS will mark only the contents of the value, including both `'` (tested in VS2012).

Comment: This works, however, how could i get only after itemId?

Comment: What you mean exactly? The regex above only catches the value after `itemId`.

Comment: maybe it's an issue with visual studio ide for searching via regular expressions but i had to omit / & /g in order to get the ide to recognize the expression which is changing my results.  I ended up using this variation which works but includes the itemId. `itemId:\s?'(.+?)'`

Comment: Oh sure! the `/` are usual regex-delimiters and the `g` is a regex-flag - perhaps you wanna read up on this. When using search&replace in any texteditor you have to omit these. The `g` flag is equivalent to "replace all" in this case (if you're replacing anything).

Comment: @weeksdev see my update, this way VS won't mark the `itemId` anymore

Comment: You're welcome. If the single quotes (`'`) are still too much to be included in the result, then go for `(?<=itemId:\s?').+?(?=')`.

Answer (score 2):

RegExp: `/(?<=(itemid:\s\')|(itemid:\'))([^\']*)(?=\')/gi`

DEMO - http://regexr.com?37tfk

Comment: Thanks, that is close, however, I am looking specifically for the first instance in single quotes after the word `itemId`

Comment: @weeksdev: this will give only the word inside the quote but check with itemid is there or not

Comment: This works. Sorry to add to requirements, is there a way to specify either space or no space after the `:` before first `'`.  The code sometimes autoformats to have a quote and other times does not. [Example](http://regexr.com?37tfb)

Comment: @Basti M solved my other issue mentioned in his implementation above, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should limit your expression:

```
itemId:\s*'([^']+)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT3bD7)